# How to add an X11 Core font on RHEL6

Tags: fonts

I wish to add at least one X11 core font to my RHEL6 system.  I want it to be fixed pitch and about the size of a standard 16 popint font (as one would see in, say, MS Word).  I can find a hundred sites that tell me ABOUT fonts, that list Open/Susue fonts or Mandrivia fonts, but none that amounts to a "download this to there and do these steps to install it" page.

Can someone point me to a supply of fixed pitch XX1 core fonts complete with install instructions?

Comment: Corefonts tend to refer to a specific set of fonts released by MS some time back - do you mean those?

Comment: Well, no, not as far as I know.  I just used the words given to me by someone else.  I want the old X11 fonts like "fixed" of  "-misc-fixed-medium-r-*-*-20-200-75-75-*-*-*-*" except with the 200 more like 300.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'd use the RHEL package manager (`yum`?) to check what X11 packages are installed and maybe add something like [X11 Misc fonts](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=xorg-x11-fonts-misc) (I haven't checked whats in that, just an example)

Comment: Sadly, I'm behind a corporate stupidity wall.  I can't get to most YUM repositories.  Now, if they came in RPMs...